# Interactive Flow Chart

Tags: java, python-3.x, diagram

I have written a few C programs that are pretty extensive. I am looking to draw a flow chart/ER Diagram of how the header files are called and which call to which. While I could use Visio and draw this in a few hours, I am looking to make an interactive diagram. I have started one in Python using Imagine Magick but I am wondering whether Java/JavaFX/JavaGraphics would be the best way to go about this task. Any suggestions for the most efficient way to make a program that will draw a diagram of my large scale project?

NOTE: Python has worked thus far and it has drawn a small scale diagram with arrows to each relation but it is slow.

Comment: Library recommendations are off topic for StackOverflow, that said, some tools you may wish to look into are: [yworks](https://www.yworks.com) or [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org) and [jgraph](https://www.jgraph.com).  Unless the interface is super basic, you are probably best off using an existing library API rather than building the functionality yourself.  JavaScript based interfaces can be embedded in a [WebView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html), if you need a standalone runtime container for them outside of a browser.

Comment: Related: [Java graph library for visualising flowchart-like diagrams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843442/java-graph-library-for-visualising-flowchart-like-diagrams)